# Ignoring h2o factor in GLM

Tags: h2o

When you one-hot encode categorical variables, you usually drop one of the variables before modeling. That way, you don't have a redundant feature that is linearly dependent on the others.

Is there a way to specify a level of the categorical variable that should not be used in fitting?

From [the documentation](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/glm.html):
"We strongly recommend avoiding one-hot encoding categorical columns with any levels into many binary columns, as this is very inefficient. This is especially true for Python users who are used to expanding their categorical variables manually for other frameworks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is "no": you leave that decision up to H2O, so it can do it efficiently. The [section just after the one you linked to](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/glm.html#handling-of-numeric-variables) explains why:

> When GLM performs regression (with factor columns), one category can be left out to avoid multicollinearity. If regularization is disabled (lambda = 0), then one category is left out. However, when using a the default lambda parameter, all categories are included.
>
> The reason for the different behavior with regularization is that collinearity is not a problem with regularization. And it’s better to leave regularization to find out which level to ignore (or how to distribute the coefficients between the levels).

As an aside, it seems all the other algorithms allow control over the categorical encoding:
http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/categorical_encoding.html